# MYSQL query data is not displaying properly

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

hi guys im  new to mysql, i have trouble with displaying my table data, not sure what i am doing wrong..

this is my query for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales20102017(
date DATE NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
postal_code VARCHAR(10) NULL,
county VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
price BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
not_full_market_price ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL,
vat_exclusive ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL,
property_description  VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
size_description VARCHAR(40) NULL
);
```

and my load data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/sales20102017.csv"
INTO TABLE sales20102017
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

and my excel data:

[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld0bK.png)

this is the result i get when i display it on mysql 
[mysql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVAGz.png)

the table is not in order and everything is just messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for fields containing commas in csv file import on Mysql.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/sales20102017.csv"
INTO TABLE sales20102017
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

See more on [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Check for fields containing commas in csv file import on Mysql, do you mean i should change some stuffs in the csv file?

the query you gave me is working tho it's displaying the current data i have properly! tysm

Comment: No need to change csv file. You can accept answer if my query works.